# Optimization where we have a 2-d decision variable matrix in R

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to do an optimization in R which will give the products to be produced in 3 different machines across 20 days. There are 15 products. The objective is to maximize the total production.

The data has a required production and the total production is calculated using the PCs to be produced per day multiplied by the weight of per PC and the total production of all the products across different machines for all days, i.e. in 20 days if product 1 is produced 7 times taking all the machines into consideration, then its total production will be (745*0.1*7), where 740 is the number of PCs to be produced and 0.1 is the weight in MT.

This will be done for all 15 products and thus we will get the objective function as the sum of the production of all the 15 products.

Now there are certain constraints like Machine 1 can produce products 1  to 4, Machine 2 can produce 5 to 12, 3 can produce 7 to 15. There has to be an increasing sequence of products in each machine each day and also the total production of each product should be greater than production required. Also Machine 3 - Machine 2 should be greater than 0.

Now when I am trying to use any optimization algorithm in R it takes initial values as a vector whereas I have a matrix and also when I am trying to define the constraints:

```
const_m1 <- function(x){
f <- NULL
f[1] <- x[,1]
f[2] <- -(x[,1]-5)
f[3] <- x[,2]-6
f[4] <- -(x[,2]-13)
f[5] <- (x[,3]-8)
f
 }
```

Then since it is a vector just one value is getting stored but actually each constraint will have 20 values since we have 20 days (the code just gives some of the constraints). I was trying to use `auglag` and thus defined the constraints such. I do not want to repeat the constraint 20 times for each machine.
How should I go about doing this.
Also, I tried writing the constraint as

```
const_m11 <- function(x){
f <- NULL
f <- rbind(f,-(x[,1]-1))
f <- rbind(f,x[,1]-4)
f <- rbind(f,-(x[,2]-5))
f <- rbind(f,x[,2]-12)
f <- rbind(f,-(x[,3]-7))
return(f)
 }
```

Again this is a just a part of the constraints and not all of them are mentioned here. I tried to use the function `solnl()` from the package `NlcOptim` but this is given an error that $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors which I am unable to understand. Please suggest how should I define the constraints and also which function will be suitable to solve my problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do in your code.  You are roughly describing a standard production planning problem that can be solved with mixed integer programming.  The first step is to take your verbal model and translate it into the standard algebraic form, i.e. objective function, constraint sets, bounds.  Then formulate the model using matrix nomenclature readable by your model manager. Recommend checking out the R optimization packages ROI and ompr.

Comment: The problem that I am trying to convey is that while writing the constraints, each of the constraint will have a single value, but in my case when I write a constraint say, the products produced in machine 1 can be greater than equal to 1 and less than equal to 5 in such a case I will have to write it 20 times, which I do not want to do but write it just once. The optimization algorithm does not accept a vector in a single constraint. This is the issue. Could you please suggest a way out.

Comment: Also the optimization function that I am working with accepts the starting variables as a vector and not as a matrix. Could someone suggest any function which accepts a matrix and helps in solving the optimization problem. This will really help.

Comment: I saw the package **ompr** and it is helpful in formulating the constraints the way needed, although I am unable to understand how to set the objective function in this particular function. Could someone please help.

Comment: Well if "total production" is the total # of units produced, then you just sum the decision variables in the objective function.  Note the variables have to be indexed by item, machine, day.  The constraints should limit the item production by machine and day.  Do a search on "optimization production planning".  Some examples/tutorials should pop up.

Comment: BTW, of course you have to filter out/not generate infeasible decision variables for your objective function and constraints.  E.g. only some machines make some products.  So feasible subsets of your indexes have to be enumerated.  There are a few ways to do it.  But beyond scope here.